# How can I send http requests when phone state changes?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, phone-state-listener

I'm listening to changes on PhoneStateListener and I want to make a url request each time there is a change. I would be grateful for any input.

I have tried to fiddle with the code below without success. The log message works fine but the request to the web-server does not work.

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener{
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state)
        {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://example.com/log.php?state=Ringing");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
            }

            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code above? Isn't it fired? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Sorry, the log message works fine but the request to the web-server does not work.

Comment: is there an execption or an error?

Comment: I can't see any errors when stepping or running at full speed

Answer (score 0):

you might not have permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

and try running the http io code in the worker thread:

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state)
        {
            new AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
                    // phone ringing
                    String incomingNumber=voids[0];
                    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/log.php?state=Ringing");
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
                    }

                    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);

                    return null;
                }
            }.execute(incomingNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

also see if there is any network problems; e.g. dns, access policy, routing issues...

Comment: Thanks. Sounds right. I tried that now, but I do not get any positive result. I do not get any error and the request do not arrive at the web-server.

Comment: i think this is a permission problem; i'll refer you to a post about that;

Comment: Thanks, I have a we view in the app that works, but maybe there are different permissions